# how insert value in database column wihch add by migration.cs in orchard

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, orchardcms

I have added a column in database table with  migration.cs file in orchard. When i insert value for that column by **actionresult**  .This value didn't appear in database. it shows only  Null value. This happen when i use UpdateFromX method to alter table  by migration.cs file

There is any way for this?

here is code to alter Table:-

```
public int UpdateFrom19()
{
    SchemaBuilder.AlterTable("EmpPartRecord", table => table.AddColumn<string>("Firstname", c => c.WithDefault( EmpPartRecord.Firstname).WithLength(1024)));
    return 20;
}
```

**While i insert value for Firstname column by Actionresult  it sends null to database .**

**ActionResult code is here:-

```
public ActionResult CreateNewEmp(string id, string nam, string add, string s)
{
    try
    {
        var News = Services.ContentManager.New("Emp");
        var obj = News.As<EmpPart>();
        obj.empno = Convert.ToInt32(id);
        obj.empnam = nam;
        obj.empad = add;
        obj.empsl = Convert.ToInt32(s);
        obj.DateOrdered = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        obj.phone = "96402";
        obj.Lastname = "hello";
        obj.Firstname = "hello";
        Services.ContentManager.Create(obj);
    }
    catch (Exception hj)
    {
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: You will need to provide your migrations and action result code... Also check the Orchard error logs

Comment: public int UpdateFrom19()
        {
            SchemaBuilder.AlterTable("EmpPartRecord", table => table
           .AddColumn<string>("Firstname", c => c.WithDefault( EmpPartRecord.Firstname).WithLength(1024)));


            return 20;
        }

Comment: Yes, I Had Checked  Orchard Error Logs there no error or exception

Comment: In the body of the question, using proper formatting, not in a comment.